# Добавить слово в строку после последней буквы

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

Есть строки вот такого вида

```
dsdddfffdfd:dsds1980
dsddd1fff11dfd:ds1ds1987
ds111ddfffdfd:dsdw12s1981
```

Нужно после последней буквы в каждой строке добавить слово **Test**. То есть результат должен быть:

```
dsdddfffdfd:dsds**Test**1980
dsddd1fff11dfd:ds1ds**Test**1987
ds111ddfffdfd:dsdw12s**Test**1981
```

Добавить в конце строки то понятно как:
S:= S + 'Test';

Но вот как решить эту задачу то понятия нет.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/R1218e/1

Comment: @teran, Я ввожу RegExp.Expression:='/(\d+)$/gm' в коде программы и ничего не происходит. Просто никогда не работала я с регулярными выражениями. Но сам модуль подключил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

задача для метода `TRegEx.replace()`. На вход получает строку текста, шаблон и строку замены.

```
result := TRegEx.replace(txt, '(\d+)$', '**test**\1');
```

в шаблоне `$` - конец строки, `()` - группа захвата, ее извлекаем из строки. `\d+` - одна и более цифр. Далее в строке замены можем обратиться (обратная ссылка) к группе захвата с номером 1 (в 0 - вся строка соответствия) через `\1`.

Comment: Спасибо. Только при компиляции получаю ошибку: Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'string'

Comment: @Татьяна какую версию Delphi используете?

Comment: Использую - Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin

Comment: class function Replace(const Input, Pattern, Replacement: string): string возвращает строку, поэтому присваивать нужно переменной строкового типа.

Comment: вообще говоря, группа захвата нам не нужна здесь, можно просто `\d+$` заменить на `test\0`

Comment: @teran, Все равно ошибка Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'string Ну ничего буду разбираться сейчас. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Вот код, который у меня работает:

```
Label1.Caption:='aaaaaaaa'+#13#10+'bbbbbbb'+#13#10+'cccccccc';
Label2.Caption:=StringReplace(Label1.Caption,#13#10,'Test'+#13#10,[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase])+'Test';
```

Костыль, но работающий :)

При желании можна причесать, но хотел указать на два момента, с которыми вы имеете дело:

1. Символ переноса в конце строки `#13#10` (Enter).
2. Функция `StringReplace`, которую я использовал для замены (можно и покрасивее сделать).

Comment: Вы, вероятно, не заметили, что после последней буквы могут быть цифры или другие символы

Comment: Тогда у меня вопрос - чем заканчивается каждая строка? Какой символ формируют следующую строку?

Comment: Здесь не стоит задача получения концов строк и разделения длинного набора на отдельные строки. Вот просто - есть строка, в конце которой могут быть не буквы.

Comment: тогда в чем проблема с ответом S:= S + 'Test'; ?

Comment: Кажется, я понял, в чём дело - вы путаете символы (общее понятие) с буквами (подмножеством символов)